# PHP type Callable - is possible send parameter

Tags: php, oop

i have class for errors and i use it this way:

```
set_error_handler("Error::catchError");
```

I need send to this class and method info, where is log file placed, but i cant figure out, if is possible send some parameter with this call. I dont want and i cant define way to file directly in method catchError.

Thank very much to all for all ideas.

This is my Error class:

```
class Error{    

    /** Catch PHP error and choose what to do with it
     * @param int error type
     * @param string error message
     * @param err_file string filename that the error was raised in
     * @param err_line int line number the error was raised at 
     * @param err_context array every variable that existed in the scope the error was triggered in  * 
     */
    public static function catchError($err_no, $err_str, $err_file, $err_line, $err_context){
        $log_file = "C:/wamp/www/cms/error.log"; // THIS MUST BE OBTAINED BY PARAMETER
        $date =  date("[Y-m-d h:i:s]",time());
        $client_ip = "[".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."]";
        $text = " Error n: $err_no: $err_str on line $err_line in $err_file\n";
        file_put_contents($log_file, $date.$client_ip." ".$text, FILE_APPEND);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want help you will have to show us your implementation of the Error class

Comment: It is done now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anonymous function:

```
set_error_handler(function ($err_no, $err_str, $err_file, $err_line, $err_context) {
    Error::catchError('error.log', $err_no, $err_str, $err_file, $err_line, $err_context);
});
```

Or rewrite your `Error` class so you can instantiate it and pass the log to the constructor (way better method anyway):

```
$logger = new Error('error.log');
set_error_handler(array($logger, 'catchError'));
```